# Which tense is "It is done."?

Tags: tense

I don't remember which tense included BE + V3. For example: It is done.
So which was it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It is done" is written in the **present tense**. Nothing more complicated than that.

What I think is confusing you is the word "done". Done can either be the past participle of do or an adjective. In this case it's being used an adjective, not a verb.

"It is blue" or "It is big" are no different from a grammatical perspective than the phrase "It is done".